# Getting mongostats from pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

From a remote machine; how can I use mongostat from pymongo to get mongostats from pymongo?
I am usinng rep sets.

```
c = Connection("50.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017",replicaSet='test')
rep_status = c.admin.command("replSetGetStatus")
mongostat = c.admin.command("mongostat")

pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command SON([('mongostat', 1)]) failed: no such cmd: mongostat
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the serverStatus command:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/server-status/

You can call it from pymongo like `c.admin.command("serverStatus")`

All the same information that's in mongostat is present in the results of serverStatus (in fact, all mongostat is doing behind the scenes is running the serverStatus command, and formatting/printing the output).

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) in the stdlib:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["ls", "-l"])
```

You'll need to call `mongostat --host HOST --port PORT` .
To connect to a replica set, you can specify the replica set seed name, and a seed list of set members, in the following format:

`<replica_set_name>/<hostname1><:port>,<hostname2:<port>,...`

Comment: Just to expand a little upon what Nick wrote: mongostat is not a mongodb-internal command, it is a program that executes outside of mongodb.  This means you cannot call it from inside mongodb, but rather must call it from the operating system.  The python call function that Nick mentions is method for making system calls just like you might from a shell (hence the "ls -l" example)

Comment: and can I assign the result to a variable. Like `result = call(["ls", "-l"])`?